# Front page of a paper review

Tags: header-footer, article, journal

I have to write a review of a scientific paper, and my teacher wants me to write title, journal name, volume, number, pages, year, authors and their affiliations.

By now I got to this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Paper title}
\subtitle{\textit{\textmd{Review by me}}}

\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

\author[a]{authors}
\affil[a]{contacts}

\date{23-01-2019}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I don't like the result, and it's not yet finished. If I wrote also journal infos I would get a bunch of header lines aesthetically awful.

So my question is: how can I write all those infos for a paper review in an aesthetically pleasant way? Is there any useful package?

EDIT based on comments: aesthetically pleasant is definetely too vague. Let's put it this way, any document type or packages (even more than one) that lets me input those labels so that it automatically sets up the front page. For example the article document type lets me input the title, author and date, with scrartcl I can also insert the subtitle, authblk is useful for authors' affiliations. But then I wouldn't know where to write the journal and etc and I'm sure that if I wrote it "by hand" I would mess up things. Hope I was clearer

Comment: Should the authors of the reviewed article be on the front page? Where should your name go? Could you make a sketch of what you want to achieve somehow and upload it here?

Comment: Well, what do you mean with a "aesthetically pleasant way"? Is this not very personal opinion?

Comment: Edit the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've redefined the macro `\maketitle` which should now be able to do what you want. There is a new macro `\reviewer` that adds well, the reviewer to the title. If you need more than one reviewer, you can separate them by `\and`. `\reviewer` doesn't support affiliation or the like. If you need those, I could add it, just let me know in the comments.

The new `\maketitle` does only support the entries

- `\title`
- `\subtitle`
- `\reviewer`
- `\author`
- `\date`

If you need anything else, like a `\dedication` or an image, let me know in the comments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

\makeatletter
\let\@reviewer\@empty
\newcommand\reviewer[1]{\gdef\@reviewer{#1}}
\renewcommand*\maketitle
  {%
    \begin{center}
      \mbox{}\par
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \huge{\bfseries\sffamily\@title}\par
      \ifx\@subtitle\@empty
      \else
        \vskip-\smallskipamount
        \begingroup\large\sffamily\mdseries\@subtitle\endgroup\par
      \fi
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \large
      \ifx\@reviewer\@empty
      \else
        \begingroup\sffamily\mdseries\itshape Review by\endgroup\par
        \smallskip
        \begingroup
          \Large
          \def\and{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\ and \ignorespaces}%
          \mdseries\@reviewer
        \endgroup
        \par
        \bigskip
        \begingroup\sffamily\mdseries\itshape Original authors\endgroup\par
        \smallskip
      \fi
      \begingroup\Large\@author\endgroup\par
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \begingroup\Large\@date\endgroup\par
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
    \end{center}%
  }
\makeatother

\title{Paper title}
\subtitle{Serious subtitle}%

\reviewer{me\and him}
\author[a]{authors}
\author[b]{more authors}
\affil[a]{contacts}
\affil[b]{more contacts}

\date{23-01-2019}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text starting the review
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's fine thank you. I added the field "publishers" before the title using your code as example